# How can I run f-droid apps on ubuntu?

Tags: android

Is there a lightweight, opensource solution, which integrates well with gnome to run [f-droid](https://f-droid.org/) apps on the Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: On the f-droid site I could find only information on how to install a repository on ubuntu?

Comment: "F-Droid is an installable catalogue of FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) applications for the Android platform."  soooo you will need an android platform. Have a look at Genymotion And NO to the "run on Ubuntu" part. Only emulation.

Comment: Maybe you could try with Anbox?

Comment: @ByteCommander I think that's the best solution, please make this an answer.

Comment: @v217 I don't know, my only experience with Anbox was that I tried to install it once back when it was in early alpha and it broke my system... Didn't touch it since then, but I assume it has improved quite a lot since then. If you manage to get it working, an answer by yourself with a brief description of how you did it exactly would be worth much more than me mentioning the software name. :)

Comment: @ByteCommander OK, then I really hope the software has improved!

Comment: https://anbox.io/ works great so far

Answer (score 2):

As answered you can use F-Droid on Android, so I assume you are looking for an android emulator.
You can try https://www.android-x86.org/ in a virtual machine and install f-droid on there. Other Emulators are pretty buggy, which is why I would like you to try this.

Comment: I think it's possible with a google chrome extension to run android apps on ubuntu. This would be definitely a more lightweight solution than android-x86. Plus android-x86 doesn't integrate well with gnome!

Comment: I am not sure if google chrome would accept F-Droid though, which is why I recommended something that they have no say in whatsoever.
If it turns out that Google Chrome does run F-Droid then my apologies.

Comment: I am just wondering why I couldn't find no better solutions surely lot's of people would find this useful, so I will leave this question open a bit more

Answer (score -2):

At a terminal window, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install fdroidserver` as per
https://fdroid.org/en/docs/Installing_the_Server_and_Repo_Tools/#debianubuntumintetc

Comment: why the downvotes?